# wrong title when posting action with opengraph in recent activity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed

i'm trying to post an action with open graph everything is fine & the story in newsfeed  is ok but something in the activity in user's timeline is wrong

newsfeed:
[image]
timeline :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'a view' is the type of object you have created. I suggest you rename this to what you want it to say on timeline.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: i found the problem before but thank s again :) 
problem was because of wrong og:title in my page